# Is there an R function or package that allows joining by columns with custom matching criteria, possibly via supplied functions?

Tags: r

I want to join two tibbles that contain columns similar to this,

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(id = 1:7,
            my_col = c(NA, 
                       "4352534j", 
                       "0342852 02742t35",
                       "971843 3245", 
                       "804263", 
                       "78asd1745",
                       "87hn73"))

y <- tibble(id = 1:6,
            other_col = c("taco232",
                          "4352534j",
                          "3245",
                          "78asd1745",
                          "0342852",
                          "78asd1745"))
```

such that the result is similar to this:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
   id.x my_col            id.y other_col
  <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 NA                  NA NA       
2     2 4352534j             2 4352534j 
3     3 0342852 02742t35     5 0342852  
4     4 971843 3245          3 3245     
5     5 804263              NA NA       
6     6 78asd1745            4 78asd1745
7     6 78asd1745            6 78asd1745
8     7 87hn73              NA NA       
9    NA NA                   1 taco232
```

This can be done by (more or less) with a cartesian join followed by a filter, but that's less efficient. I am aware of [fuzzy_join](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html), but I don't think that's exactly what I want (I could have missed something though).

I would like to customize the criteria used to match the column values (keys) with each other. Perhaps this can be done with some package's "full join" function with a function argument that declares the matching rules. Here's an idea of how it could work (not necessarily how it *should* work):

```
match_criteria <- function(colx, coly) {
  if (str_detect(colx, coly)) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}

# fancy_full_join does not exist
fancy_full_join(x, y, by = list(fun = match_criteria("my_col", "other_col"), 
                                keep = "both"))
```

What is a solution that does this? It doesn't have to be on CRAN, but it seems like there'd already be a fairly simple conventional way to do it with data.table or dplyr.

Comment: Sounds like you do want the `fuzzy_join` package.  `fuzzy_full_join(x, y, by = c("my_col" = "other_col"), match_fun = str_detect)` if you're looking for by column matches of `y` in `x` or maybe `fuzzy_full_join(x, y, by = c("my_col" = "other_col"), match_fun = ~ str_detect(.x, .y) | str_detect(.y, .x))` if you want it bi-directional.

Comment: If you can mutate the columns in each tibble first, then join them, that would be most efficient.  Fuzzy joins are slow in comparison.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, this works as intended and is exactly the kind of thing I want to use. This should be an answer instead of a comment. If you converted it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
x %>% 
    mutate(other_col = str_split(my_col, " ")) %>% 
    unnest(other_col) %>% 
    full_join(y, by = "other_col") %>% 
    group_by(id.x) %>% 
    filter(n()==1 | !is.na(id.y)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
   id.x my_col           other_col  id.y
  <int> <chr>            <chr>     <int>
1     1 NA               NA           NA
2     2 4352534j         4352534j      2
3     3 0342852 02742t35 0342852       5
4     4 971843 3245      3245          3
5     5 804263           804263       NA
6     6 78asd1745        78asd1745     4
7     6 78asd1745        78asd1745     6
8     7 87hn73           87hn73       NA
9    NA NA               taco232       1
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, just case specific.